# CSS on bootstrap tables not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I use following css in my table:

```
.lh1 {
    line-height: 50px;
    }
```

And my table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered lh lh1">
..
..
..
</table>
```

But no matter which value I use for line-height, my table doesn't change at all. Other .css in this table is working fine.

What could be the cause of that problem?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this.

CSS

```
.lh1 > tbody > tr > td {
    line-height: 50px;
    }
```

your CSS is not overwriting the bootstrap CSS. Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fnxaH)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
.lh1 {
   line-height: 50px !important;
}
```

Your bootstrap may override this